I am bundling nodejs application as a single executable. How can I set it up as a service on Windows?
I was using NSSM for setting up my nodejs application as a service on Windows. However, NSSM is not developed or maintained any more. What can I use to replace NSSM. I have explored pm2 but it seems I cannot use it in the single executable nodejs bundle.
